# How to access the Index of a changed Selection in a Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a windows form. Currently I am geting quite a headache over a seemingly simple prolbem.

I have a datagridview and want to allow right click selection. Therefore I created a function called dataGridViewJobs_MouseDown that is raised on MouseDown on the datagridview:

```
private void dataGridViewJobs_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int curRowIdx = dataGridViewJobs.HitTest(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y).RowIndex;
    if (curRowIdx != -1 && curRowIdx < dataGridViewJobs.Rows.Count)
    {
        dataGridViewJobs.CurrentCell = dataGridViewJobs[0, curRowIdx];
    }
}
```

A hitTest is executed to find the row-index of the clicked cell. Afterwards the currentCell of the datagridview is set to the first cell in said row.

This causes the SelectionChanged-event to be raised. This is connected to the following function:

```
private void dataGridViewJobs_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridViewJobs.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(dataGridViewJobs.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
    }
 }
```

This writes the old index to the console. Why is that?

I am currently working with a workaround, which means I save the result of the hitTest in a global variable. But that can not be the right way to do this.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is the order of events when you expand a selection with the mouse:  `MouseDown >  CellMouseDown >  CurrentCellChanged >  SelectionChanged >  Click >  CellClick >  MouseClick >  CellMouseClick >  CellMouseUp >  MouseUp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When you change the value of the CurrentCell property, the
>   SelectionChanged event occurs before the CurrentCellChanged event. Any
>   SelectionChanged event handler accessing the CurrentCell property at
>   this time will get its previous value.

Use `CurrentCellChanged` event for printing current value